# FullCalendar beforeLoad & afterLoad Callbacks

Tags: fullcalendar

Are there any callbacks in FullCalendar that trigger before Calendar load or after the calendar completely loads?  Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
loading: function (bool) { 
  if (bool) 
     $('#loadingImg').show(); 
   else 
     $('#loadingImg').hide(); 
     //Possibly call you feed loader to add the next feed in line
},
```

If any event rendering or fetching for ALL the sources is happening it will be `TRUE` otherwise it will trigger and goto to `FALSE`

There is no other way to determine if a particular feed has loaded or is being loaded.

You would have to implement your own logic using the loading

where you would use

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', 'diaryFeed.aspx?style=Basic');
```

wait for load to finish and trigger to add the next source.. etc

Comment: Thank you for the help!  This is exactly what I needed.  I wanted the calendar to go back to the month that a user selected, if they moved to another page and then hit the back button.  So I set a cookie of the currently displayed calendar and then when the calendar is reloaded it checks to see if the date is selected and then goes back to that month.

Answer (score 5):

There are a few options you can use,

`loading` can be used to trigger events while loading and after loading [More Info](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/loading/)

or you can use [eventRender](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/loading/) and [eventAfterRender](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/eventAfterRender/) to trigger before each event is rendered and after each event has rendered.

Hope this helps!

Comment: as of 1.6, there's also `eventAfterAllRender`:  http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/eventAfterAllRender/